# Looking to incorporate 3rd party software reviews into my website

Tags: web-apps

I get mostly reviews of my software via email and my software forums, but few of these people add a software review on third party site. Is there something I could add to my site that allows them to easily review my software ( similar like tripadvisor) , but controlled by a 3rd party so website visitors can have confidence these are real reviews.

Requirements

1. Can easily be added to a html based website
2. Allow users to review my software via text and a score
3. Provided by trusted 3rd party so users not concerned they are not real reviews.
4. Inexpensive or free, less than $30 a month

Comment: Can you expand on what specific review sites you want? Right now, your question seems a little opinion based as some people may find certain review sites credible while others may not.

Comment: If you look at travel TripAdvisor has gained alot of credence, I wonder if there is something simailr for software. MacUpdate reviews are generally well trusted but you have to go to the macupdate site to write the reviews I want people to be able to do an easy review on my site, but of course the reviews have to be adminstered by a third aprty not me

Comment: I understand that and that's a more credible way to administer reviews, but you need to specify the review sites **you** find credible and the ones that **you** want on your website.

Comment: I dont know of a single review site that lets reviews be entered via my website so any suggestions would be better than the current situation

Comment: @Tom cant you give me an actual answer, there is a bounty available

Answer (score 2):

Though not sure what platform you are using, but WP Customer Reviews seems to have a fairly solid 5* backing - https://wordpress.org/plugins/wp-customer-reviews/

The data is stored in Microdata / Microformat, so user and engine friendly as well, and it has a few goodies for management tasks too.

There's a free and a pro version as well. Might be worth contacting them to seem if it can be integrated with your site.

Comment: I was looking for a system that was adminstered by a 3rd party to give users confidence in the reviews, but thankyou this might be the next best thing.

Comment: Paul, how exactly would that be embedded in your site? Would it be like a, say, javascript that loads the external content, so the 3rd party nature would guarantee that the reviews are legit?

Comment: Somthing like that, I may have foind what Im looking for with https://uk.trustpilot.com/